# execute mongo commands without connecting to db each time

Tags: bash, mongodb

```
while read -r line
do
        number = "ranom id generator"
        mongo domains --eval "var isexist=db.domains.findOne({name: '$name'}); if(!isexist){db.domains.insert({_id: '$number',name: '$name'})}"
done < "$FIL.final"
```

this is my bash script, main snippet

```
mongo domains --eval "var isexist=db.domains.findOne({name: '$name'}); if(!isexist){db.domains.insert({_id: '$number',name: '$name'})}"
    done < "$FIL.final"
```

Here, I'm reading each line from large file and inserting into db,

but here I'm connecting to db each time while inserting the code,

in my server console I see this for each version

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
connecting to: domains
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
connecting to: domains
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
connecting to: domains
..................
```

But I want to connect to DB and insert the records, so I can save time, the script running,
HOw to do this?

Comment: You could use mongoimport for one. But aside from making some clever code to eval your entire block I think you have to call the mongo console eval each time, resulting in a new connection each time

Comment: Why do you generate your own random `_id`'s? MongoDB automatically generates a unique ObjectId when inserting a new document without id. Further, instead of querying to check if a document exist and then enter it depending on the response, you can use an update with [`upsert:true`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option).

Comment: @Philipp, I'm working with meteor,so `objectId` generated by mongo will not work in app

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script to create one large string of Javascript code in the loop. After the loop, call `mongo domains --eval` once with the string you created.

Comment: I need to pass $name to the script, I tried it but I can't pass variable to script